# How can I structure common data while retaining defaulted move ctor and assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have a few classes that share things in common: the way they are constructed and the data they hold. However, each had a unique dtor. So, it seemed obvious to try to remove code duplication and make them inherit from a base class. So I started out with this:

```
class base{
protected:
    int data;
public:
    base() = default;
    base(const base &) = delete;
    base& operator=(const base &) = delete;
    base(base &&) = default;
    base& operator=(base &&) = default;
};

class derived: public base{
public:
    ~derived() {}
};
```

However, a problem arises. I can't do this

```
derived d;
derived e(std::move(d));
```

The reason is because `derived` declares a dtor, meaning that move ctor/assignment do not get generated. So my next thought was to invert the inheritance, and I came up with this. Since I would have (in my original example) had multiple derived and a single base, the way I thought of doing this was to have multiple bases and a single derived, which would be templated to point to the different bases.

```
class base1{
public:
    ~base1() {}
};

class base2{
public:
    ~base2() {}
};

template<class T>
class derived: public T{
protected:
    int data;
public:
    derived() = default;
    derived(const derived &) = delete;
    derived& operator=(const derived &) = delete;
    derived(derived &&) = default;
    derived& operator=(derived &&) = default;
};

using derived1 = derived<base1>;
using derived2 = derived<base2>;
```

This is all fine and dandy, and it compiles!
However, `base1` and `base2` need access to the element `data` in `base`, and so I thought making the bases a templated class, so that their functions can access `data`. Also, the bases actually are sometimes templated, so I need to add this functionality as well. What I have so far is this:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class base1{
public:
    ~base1() {
        std::cout<<T1::data;
    }
};

template<class T>
class base2{
public:
    ~base2() {
        std::cout<<T::data;
    }
};

template<template <class, class...> class T, class... Ts>
class derived: public T<typename derived, Ts...>{
protected:
    int data;
public:
    derived() = default;
    derived(const derived &) = delete;
    derived& operator=(const derived &) = delete;
    derived(derived &&) = default;
    derived& operator=(derived &&) = default;
};

using derived1int = derived<base1<int>>;
using derived1float = derived<base1<float>>;
using derived2 = derived<base2>;
```

However, I am sure there are a lot of errors. The compiler error I get right now in GCC 4.9 is (when only using `derived2`) is that template argument 1 is invalid in the class derived.

Comment: Why does your class need to define a destructor? That seems a bit odd if the implicitly defined move special member functions are good enough.

Comment: Note: the `base` class should have a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: The reason for a destructor is because I am wrapping some OpenGL functions, such as VBOs, framebuffers, programs, etc. So what I do is have a `gen()` function that generates them and the dtor takes care of deleting the data when it's done with.

I don't need a virtual dtor since I do not intend on using a base pointer to derived.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply redeclare the (defaulted) move constructor and move assignment operators in the derived classes?

Comment: If you create dedicated RAII class, and use it as member in `derived`, you won't need to have a user defined destructor in `derived` anymore.

Comment: I can redeclare them, which is what I was doing. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it with templates. I don't need a defined destructor in `derived` in my last example. I need it in the bases, which are the dedicated RAII classes.

Comment: @user975989 The point I was trying to make was, if you need to destructor to perform cleanup of frame buffers and what not, how is it that you don't need a move constructor definition to transfer ownership of these correctly? You can achieve what you want by following Jarod's advice. Wrap these objects that need special handling in dedicated RAII classes, and then you don't need to define the destructor anymore in the classes that contain them.

Comment: I am trying to define RAII classes. That is the whole point of this. If I could write the dedicated RAII classes, that would be the solution to this problem. The reason why default move/assign are fine is because the only data that is needed is the `data`, which in reality just holds a handler for a OpenGL buffer. I originally had each type of buffer be its own class, but I wanted to reuse the code so I don't have to write `= default` for each class, and to reduce code duplication. I understand that this is a question that can be solved in another means, but I would like to know a solution.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. By RAII class, I don't mean a class that does 5 different things and cleans up those 5 things in the destructor. You should write a `opengl_handle` class for instance, and the only thing it knows to do is manage the lifetime of the handle it owns. Write little wrappers like that, put them into `derived` and then `derived` doesn't need a destructor anymore.

Comment: Your comment about the default move constructor doesn't sense either. If I'm move constructing instance `b` from instance `a` (where `a` already holds an OpenGL handle), then you need to define your own move constructor so that `a`'s handle can be set to some invalid value to indicate that it no longer owns that handle. Otherwise both `a` and `b` will try to destroy the handle in their destructors.

Comment: This was a flaw, that is entirely my bad. However, the question still stands as to how to instantiate the `derived`.

Comment: @user975989: Except if I miss a point, but with our suggestion, `derived` no longer has user defined destructor, so has auto-generated move constructor, and your initial problem disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there were valid arguments made in the comments, I managed to create the template. Here it is in case someone else needs to work out the template part:

```
template<class T1, class Data>
class base1{
public:
    ~base1() {
        std::cout<<static_cast<T1*>(this)->data << " " <<typeid(std::declval<Data>()).name();
    }
};

template<class T>
class base2{
public:
    ~base2() {
        std::cout<< static_cast<T*>(this)->data;
    }
};

template<template <class, class...> class T, class ... Ts >
class derived: public T< derived<T, Ts...>, Ts...>{
    friend class T<derived<T, Ts...>, Ts...>;
    int data = 0;
public:
    derived() = default;
    derived(const derived &) = delete;
    derived& operator=(const derived &) = delete;
    derived(derived && d){
        std::swap(data, d.data);
    }
    derived& operator=(derived && d){
        std::swap(data, d.data);
        return *this;
    }
};

using derived1int = derived<base1, int>;
using derived1float = derived<base1, float>;
using derived2 = derived<base2>;
```